# can't find imported module error in ember-cli project

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-components

I wanted to wrap a function named loanCalc in a module to be consumed by other Ember objects in an Ember-cli project.  I did the following:

```
 $ ember g util loanCalc
```

Ember-cli creates a file named app/loan-calc.js.
loan-calc.js looks like this:

```
 export default function loanCalc() {
    // other regular javascript code
 return ...}
```

I tried to use loanCalc in a component by importing the module using:

```
 import {loanCalc} from '../../../../utils/loan-calc.js';
```

When I run the application, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module 'tw/utils/loan-calc.js' imported from 'tw/pods/components/scenarios/display-scenario/component'
```

The component.js file is located in tw/app/pods/components/scenario/display-scenaro.  The loan-calc.js file is located in tw/app/utils.

The file is clearly there.  What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to do something in the ember-cli-build.js file or some other ember-cli-generated files to make this work?  I'm new to ember-cli and still trying to find my way around.

**Update**
I copied loan-calc.js into the same directory as my component, and tried to import using:

```
import {loanCalc} from 'loan-calc.js';
```

I got the same error:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module 'loan-calc.js' imported from 'tw/pods/components/scenarios/display-scenario/component'
```

Did I miss a step somewhere, or maybe something wrong with my naming convention?

**Update**

Same error when I tried:

```
  import loanCalc from 'app-name/utils/loan-calc.js';
```

I'm actually trying to import into a component.  Is the procedure different?

Comment: `import loanCalc from 'app-name/utils/loan-calc.js';`

Comment: Doesn't work.  Got the same error with a different directory path.

Comment: Late to the party but have you tired importing it in your `ember-cli-build.js`? along the lines of `app.import('app-name/utils/loan-calc.js');`